# how to work with Self hosted WCF service

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

I have successfully hosted the WCF service in windows forms application. Now what I need is a way when my service is used by any client i want to show in the form where the service is hosted that last accessed date and time from the client machine and client id.

So when ever my client is using any operation on my service is also sending me its date and time as well everything is working fine but unable to display it on the form in a label.

Can somebody suggest me please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would to use the logging and tracing that comes with WCF, you will have to write custom code to read the client logged information

Please see links that might help you

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730918.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751795.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the Microsoft Message Queue (MSMQ), which plays nicely [together with WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731089%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). MSMQ is lightwheight to use and fast, and the best of it, it is built-in into Windows and supported out-of-the-box into .NET Framework. You can decide to send messages transactional and persisted or have them priorised, if you wish.

The WCF service would send a message with your needed information each time an operation is called that you want to log in your WinForms application.

The Forms application would then receive the message asynchronously and write onto your screen or logfile or wherever you need.

Reading and writing from/ to the MSMQ in C# is straightforward.

Here is a good starting point: **Tom Hollander's blog**

- [MSMQ, WCF and IIS: Getting them to play nice (Part 1)](http://blogs.msdn.com/tomholl/archive/2008/07/12/msmq-wcf-and-iis-getting-them-to-play-nice-part-1.aspx)
- [MSMQ, WCF and IIS: Getting them to play nice (Part 2)](http://blogs.msdn.com/tomholl/archive/2008/07/12/msmq-wcf-and-iis-getting-them-to-play-nice-part-2.aspx)
- [MSMQ, WCF and IIS: Getting them to play nice (Part 3)](http://blogs.msdn.com/tomholl/archive/2008/07/12/msmq-wcf-and-iis-getting-them-to-play-nice-part-3.aspx)

Comment: Jens, there is no way that I can use the same form which is currently hosting the WCF service to read the data from the same WCF service.

Comment: @Shax: You're right and it and that is not what I meant. That is exactly **what the MSMQ is for**. Your application does **not need** to access the service **at all**. The queue exists *somewhere* on your machine => The WCF service writes the date and time information into the Message Queue  => The WinForms application reads the message and displays its data. This allows to completely decouple sender and receiver of the messages. The WCF service and WinForms app have never directly communicated with each other.